# YoloV7 Exception Dataset Not found?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, yolov7

Transferred 552/566 items from yolov7.pt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Nirajan\Desktop\Minor project\yoloV7\train.py", line 616, in 
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
File "C:\Users\Nirajan\Desktop\Minor project\yoloV7\train.py", line 97, in train
check_dataset(data_dict)  # check
File "C:\Users\Nirajan\Desktop\Minor project\yoloV7\utils\general.py", line 173, in check_dataset
raise Exception('Dataset not found.')
Exception: Dataset not found

I am trying YoloV7 model for object detection and I got this error. I have properly added the path of train, test and val in custom_data.yaml file. Yet it still gives me this error. I am trying this in Jupyter Notebook. Any solution would be great.